# SQL LEFT JOIN AND JPA / HQL Query

Tags: jpa, hql

We have hibernate 3.x (still maintaining legacy system) but I'm having difficult time
to translate this sql into HQL:

Only the table 'FS_FallSpringPlanNumber' don't have any relationship, the rest are ManyToOne and OneToMany

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBPLAN.cimPlanNumber), SUBPLAN.name FROM FS_SUBPLAN SUBPLAN
    LEFT JOIN FS_FallSpringPlanNumber FallPlanNumber ON FallPlanNumber.FallPlanNumber = SUBPLAN.cimPlanNumber
    LEFT JOIN FS_FallSpringPlanNumber SpringPlanNumber ON SpringPlanNumber.SpringPlanNumber = SUBPLAN.cimPlanNumber
    LEFT JOIN FS_PLAN FSPLAN ON FSPLAN.Name = SUBPLAN.Name
    LEFT JOIN FS_TYPE FSTYPE ON FSTYPE.UID = FSPLAN.typeUID
    LEFT JOIN FS_TERM FSTERM ON FSTERM.UID = FSTYPE.TermUID
WHERE 
    (FallPlanNumber.FallPlanNumber IS NULL) 
    AND
    (SpringPlanNumber.SpringPlanNumber IS NULL) 
    AND
     FSTERM.TermCode = 202111 AND
    (FSTERM.Name LIKE 'Fall%' OR FSTERM.Name LIKE 'Spring%')
order by SUBPLAN.cimPlanNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use a join without an actual relation in Hibernate 3.

You can use `Criteria` in place of HQL and add a relation for `FS_FallSpringPlanNumber` using `Restrictions.sqlRestriction()`.